How to code calculation of Walsh & Lawler Rainfall seasonality index in R
I am struggling to loop across multiple variables that require counters to calculate rainfall seasonality. I end up getting errors due to counters not functioning correctly or in the correct order. I would like to calculate the index for a number of different GCMs, for each year to later assess trends in rainfall seasonality.
My code is attempting to calculate rainfall seasonality using a database, DF, with the following structure:
structure(list(Date = structure(c(3651, 3651, 3651, 3651, 3651, 

3651, 3651, 3652, 3652, 3652), class = "Date"), site = structure(c(1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "Table_Mountain_NP", class = "factor"),
GCM = structure(c(13L, 15L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 14L, 13L, 15L,
7L), levels = c("ACCESS-CM2", "AWI-CM-1-1-MR", "CMCC-ESM2",
"CNRM-CM6-1", "CNRM-ESM2-1", "EC-Earth3-CC", "EC-Earth3-Veg-LR",
"GFDL-ESM4", "INM-CM4-8", "INM-CM5-0", "IPSL-CM6A-LR", "KIOST-ESM",
"MIROC-ES2L", "MIROC6", "MRI-ESM2-0", "NESM3", "NorESM2-MM",
"BCC-CSM2-MR", "CanESM5", "CESM2", "CMCC-CM2-SR5", "FGOALS-g3"
), class = "factor"), MaxTemp = c(16.75, 22.05, 22.45, 20.45,
22.05, 22.95, 25.25, 19.15, 17.55, 20.15), MinTemp = c(15.25,
16.95, 20.45, 18.15, 17.25, 19.35, 18.15, 15.05, 16.55, 18.15
), Rain = c(5.72918, 1.07309, 0.14049, 0, 0.03815, 0.04369,
0, 1.37117, 2.41574, 0.40211), AveTemp = c(16, 19.5, 21.45,
19.3, 19.65, 21.15, 21.7, 17.1, 17.05, 19.15), Year = c(1979,
1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1980, 1980, 1980), Month = c(12,
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 1, 1, 1), Season = structure(c(3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("Autumn",
"Spring", "Summer", "Winter"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA,
10L), class = "data.frame")
DF <- dat_base 
VarName <- "Rain"
  DF$Year <- as.numeric(format(DF$Date, '%Y'))
  DF$Month <- as.numeric(format(DF$Date, '%m'))
  VarIndex <- which(colnames(DF) == VarName)

# Calculate the Rainfall for each year
YearlyTotal <- aggregate(DF[, VarIndex], by = list(Year = as.numeric(format(DF$Date,'%Y')), GCM = DF$GCM), FUN = sum, na.rm = T)
 
# Calculate the total monthly rainfall for each year and month
MonthlyTotals <- aggregate(DF[, VarIndex], by = list(Year = as.numeric(format(DF$Date,'%Y')), 
                                                       Month =  as.numeric(format(DF$Date,'%m')), GCM = DF$GCM), FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)

# Merge the YearlyTotal with MonthlyTotals
Season_data <- merge(MonthlyTotals, YearlyTotal, by = c("Year","GCM"), suffixes = c("_Month", "_Year"))
  
  #Excel formula (see [https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can-anyone-help-me-in-calculating-seasonal-index-Walsh-Lawler-1981-using-excel-spreadsheet]) 
  #SI = 1/B15*(ABS(B3-B15/12)+ABS(B4-B15/12)+ABS(B5-B15/12)+ABS(B6-B15/12)+ABS(B7-B15/12)+ABS(B8-B15/12)+ABS(B9-B15/12)+ABS(B10-B15/12)+ABS(B11-B15/12)+ABS(B12-B15/12)+ABS(B13-B15/12)+ABS(B14-B15/12))
  
#Calculate the Seasonality Index
  
#SI <- 1 / YearlyTotal[,3] * rowSums(abs(MonthlyTotals[,4] - YearlyTotal[,3] / 12))

SI <- as.data.frame(NA)  

i <- unique(Season_data$Year)[1]

output <- length(unique(Season_data$GCM))*length(unique(Season_data$Year))

for (m in 1: output){
  
  for (i in i:Season_data$Year[length(Season_data$Year)]) {
 current_data <- Season_data[c(Season_data$Year == i),] 
 gcm_levels <- levels(na.omit(current_data$GCM))
  
    SI[m,1] <- i
    
    for (gcm_level in gcm_levels){
    
    subset_data <- current_data[current_data$GCM == gcm_level, ]
  
      if (length(subset_data$Month) == 12) {
      
      for (k in 1:12) { 
        
         SI[m,2] <- gcm_level  
         SI[m,3] <- 1 / subset_data$x_Year[1] * sum(abs(subset_data$x_Month[k] - subset_data$x_Year[1] / 12))
         
      }
        }
       
       else {SI[m,3] <- "NA"} 
    
  }
      }
}


I think I need another counter to keep track of the current row in SI because the loop now nests over both years and GCM levels.There should be one SI output per year.
If there is an existing function or formula that can do this calculation without needing to derive one, that would also be great!

Hello @Nicola, welcome to SO. You need to format your question as a reproducible example, including a sample of data, the attempted code (which you already included), and an outline of the expected result. Please take some time to read the link at the end and come back to edit your question. https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example

There is also a R package hydroTSM that calculates the seasonality index (si) as proposed by Walsh Lawler.

Thanks Chris. I have looked at the package, and it also only calculates the index for one year and not for each year in a dataset separately. I need to do the same calculation as in that package, but across multiple years and for multiple different data models (GCMs).

Can you show the output of dput(head(DF, 100))?

Thank you to those who responded. I was able to resolve the problem using the zoo and hydroTSM packages in combination with a for loop and an if statement as follows:
dat$Year <- as.numeric(format(dat$Date,'%Y'))
dat$Month <- as.numeric(format(dat$Date,'%m'))

SI <-data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 3)) #create database for the output
names(SI) <- c("Year","GCM","SI")
k <- 1

for (i in (dat$Year[1]+1):2099){ #loop through all the years in the main dataset

for (j in 1: length(levels(dat$GCM))){ #loop through the sub-groups within year

GCM <- levels(dat$GCM)[j]

if  (nrow(dat[c(dat$GCM == GCM & dat$Year == i),])== 0) { #if no data exists for a subgroup, then just record NA for the SI index

SI[k,1] <- i
SI[k,2] <- GCM
SI[k,3] <- NA

} else { #if data does exist for the group, then conver the current data parcel to zoo format and calculate the SI using the hydroSTM package. 

datx <- dat[c(dat$GCM == GCM & dat$Year == i),] 
datx <- zoo(datx$Rain, seq(from = datx$Date[1], to = datx$Date[length(datx$Date)], by = 1))

SI[k,1] <- i
SI[k,2] <- GCM
SI[k,3] <- si(datx) #Save the result in the SI database

} 

k <- k + 1 #loop to the next subgroup

} #loop to the next year

}

